# Render list of elements based on user's input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

**Context**
I'm new to React and so I'm building basic form where I would like to display a list of countries based on the user's input. My app is made up of two components: Filter (this is the input field where the user will enter their input) and Display (this will display the countries that meet the user's input

So far, I've been able to log the user's input to the console. However, inside the useEffect() hook, when I add in a line to update the countries state array to the user's input, nothing happens. How can I update the countries array with the user's input?

**Code**
*App.js*

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Filter from './components/Filter'
import Display from './components/Display'


function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState(['france', 'spain', 'germany', 'greece', 'portugal'])
  const [searchTerms, setSearchTerms] = useState('')
  const handleSearchInput = (event) => setSearchTerms(event.target.value)


  useEffect(() => {
   let results = countries.filter(country => country === searchTerms)
      console.log("results: ", results)
      setSearchTerms(searchTerms)
      setCountries(results)
  }, [])


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Countries</h1>
      <Filter value={searchTerms} handleChange={handleSearchInput}/>
      <Display filteredArr={countries}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*Display*

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Display({filteredArr, arr}){ 
    return(
        <p>
            {filteredArr.map(country => <div>{country}</div>)}
        </p>
    )
}
```

*Filter component*

```
export default function Filter({searchResult, handleChange}){
    return(
        <div>
            <input value={searchResult} onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Search for countries'/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the effect hook has an empty dependency array, it runs only on mount - and on mount, the `searchTerms` string is empty, so the `results` array will also be empty.

Don't use the effect hook - instead, have the `handleSearchInput` filter and set state. You'll also need a persistent list of countries - if you filter and set the state of the countries, and the user input changes again, you'll want to subsequently filter the *original* list of countries, not the already-filtered list of countries.

```js
function App() {
  const initialCountries = ['france', 'spain', 'germany', 'greece', 'portugal'];
  const [countries, setCountries] = React.useState(initialCountries)
  const [searchTerms, setSearchTerms] = React.useState('')
  const handleSearchInput = (event) => {
    setSearchTerms(event.target.value);
    setCountries(
      initialCountries.filter(
        country => country === event.target.value
      )
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Countries</h1>
      <Filter value={searchTerms} handleChange={handleSearchInput}/>
      <Display filteredArr={countries}/>
    </div>
  );
}

function Display({filteredArr, arr}){ 
    return(
        <p>
            {filteredArr.map(country => <div>{country}</div>)}
        </p>
    )
}
function Filter({searchResult, handleChange}){
    return(
        <div>
            <input value={searchResult} onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Search for countries'/>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Your current logic seems a bit odd though - do you really want to only show countries that exactly match the input? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but if you only want exact matches, it might be more user-friendly to make the countries clickable to toggle them, rather than using a text input. If you want to show multiple countries that contain the same user input substring, use `.includes` instead of `===` in the filter test.

You also might want to display all countries again if the input is empty, in which case you'd do:

```
setCountries(
  event.target.value === '' ? initialCountries : initialCountries.filter(
    country => country === event.target.value
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Ideally i'd like to display multiple countries, I didn't think to use the .includes() method.

Answer (score 0):

In useEffect Hook dependency value work  when the dependency value is change then useEffect hook is called.
useEffect(() => {
.....your code
}, [dependency])

```
 const [countries, setCountries] = useState(['france', 'spain', 
'germany', 
 'greece', 'portugal'])
  const [searchTerms, setSearchTerms] = useState('')
  const handleSearchInput = (event) =>{
  setSearchTerms(event.target.value)
  let results = countries.filter(country => country === 
 event.target.value)
  setCountries(results)
  } 


  useEffect(() => {
   let results = countries.filter(country => country === searchTerms)
   console.log("results: ", results)
   setSearchTerms(searchTerms)
   setCountries(results)
  }, [])
```

Or Only you can use this

```
   const [countries, setCountries] = useState(['france', 'spain', 
 'germany', 
 'greece', 'portugal'])
  const [searchTerms, setSearchTerms] = useState('')
  const handleSearchInput = (event) =>{
  setSearchTerms(event.target.value)
  } 

  useEffect(() => {
   let results = countries.filter(country => country === searchTerms)
   console.log("results: ", results)
   setSearchTerms(searchTerms)
   setCountries(results)
  }, [searchTerms])
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense